# Wrong amount of product with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration

My query is oriented to experts Codeigniter . I am making a purchasing system and have the following problem , adding products of different pages or rather to add products from different pages within my solution performs poorly sums .

My code

```
public function comprar($id, $titulo, $numRifa){            
        $this->load->model('rifasDB');
        $fila = $this->rifasDB->rifasDetalladaDB($id, $titulo);
        $idRifa = $numRifa;
        $nombreRifa = $numRifa;
        $precioRifa = $fila->precio;
        $insert = array( 
                 array('id' => $idRifa,
                        'qty' => 1, 
                        'price' => $precioRifa, 
                        'name' => $nombreRifa));

            $this->cart->insert($insert);
            // $datosRifas = array('idNumRifa' => $idRifa, 'idTitulo' => $id);      
            // $this->session->set_userdata($datosRifas);
            header("Location:". base_url() ."Rifas/rifasDetalladas/". $id ."/". $titulo);

    }
```

My view

```
 <li><a href=""?><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> <?php echo $this->cart->format_number($this->cart->total())?></a></li>
```

My Loops prints numbers

```
<?php while($numerosRifas <= $numRifas ){?>
            <?php $numerosRifas++?>
        <div class="col-md-3 img-portfolio">
            <!-- <a href="portfolio-item.html"> -->
            <div style="text-align:center; border:solid 22px;">
               <span style="font-weight:800; font-size:100px; text-align:center;"><?php echo $numerosRifas;?></span>
            </div> 
            <?php if($this->session->userdata('idNumRifa') == $numerosRifas && $this->session->userdata('idTitulo') == $id){?>
               <input type="button" value="COMPRAR <?php echo $numerosRifas;?>" <?php if ($pageId !== 1) echo 'disabled="disabled"' ?> />
            <?php }else{?>
                <?php if($this->session->userdata('login')){?>
                 <a href="<?= base_url()?>Rifas/comprar/<?= $id ?>/<?= $nomRifa ?>/<?= $numerosRifas?>"><input type="button" value="COMPRAR <?php echo $numerosRifas;?>" <?php if ($pageId !== 1) echo 'disabled="enabled"' ?> /></a>
                 <?php }else{?>
                    <a href="<?= base_url()?>Login"><input type="button" value="COMPRAR <?php echo $numerosRifas;?>" <?php if ($pageId !== 1) echo 'disabled="enabled"' ?> /></a>
                <?php }?>
            <?php }?>
            <!-- </a> -->
        </div>
    <?php }?>
```

I appreciate all kinds of help you can give me orienting in which the error can be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the docx

The Cart class utilizes CodeIgniter’s Session Class to save the cart information to a database, so before using the Cart class you must set up a database table as indicated in the Session Documentation, and set the session preferences in your application/config/config.php file to utilize a database.

[codeigniter cart](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html)

Comment: A table do you mean that in this part that the cart class only receives a parameter:   $this->cart->insert('your_table_name',$insert);

Comment: have u created table in your database to use the codeigniter cart